# Flatten multilevel double linked list in C - Doubts on Append function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Given a double linked list with multiple levels such as this:

[image]

I have read a solution in a book in order to Flatten the list that consists on the following code:

```
void FlattenList(node *head, node **tail)
{
    node *curNode = head;
    while (curNode) {
        if (curNode->child) {
           Append(cureNode->child, tail);
        }
    }
    curNode = curNode->next;
}

/* Apends child to the end of list and updates tail
void Append(node *child, node **tail)
{
   node *curNode;
   /* Append child child list to the end */
   (*tail)->next = child;
   child->prev = *tail;

   for(curNode = child; curNode->next; curNode = curNode->next) {
   }

   *tail = curNode;

}

typedef struct nodeT {
   struct nodeT *next;
   struct nodeT *prev;
   struct nodeT *child;
   int value;
} node;
```

My question is: Why don't we pass the child as a pointer in the APpend function? We are changing its value when doing `child->prev = *tail;` I fail to see why are we not passing a point to child if we are changing its value inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`child` is not being changed. Its member `prev` is changed.

```
child->prev = *tail;
```

will change the `child`'s `prev` and will have effect on original object as it have pointer to original object (its address).

That is why it will work.